# $f(x)=x^m+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ if only if $m=2^n$.

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

I have a question

Prove that : $f(x)=x^m+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ if only if $m=2^n$

Thanks for your helps!

Answer (score 3):

This is a consequence of the identity
$$
x^{(2n+1)2^m} + 1
= (x^{2n+1} + 1) 
(x^{(2n+1)(2^{m} - 1)}
- x^{(2n+1)(2^{m} - 2)}
 + \dots -1)
\\= (x^{2n+1} + 1)  \sum_{k=1}^{2^m}(-1)^{k-1} x^{(2n+1)(2^{m} - k)}
$$

Answer (score -2):

It's not true. If you take $f(x)=x^{6}+1$, it's irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ but $6$ is not a power of $2$. I think you want $f(x)$ irreducible iff $m=2n$.

Comment: $$x^6+1 = (x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1)$$

Comment: $x^6+1$ is not irreducible. Any root would be a $12$-th root of unity and the $12$-th cyclotomic field has degree $\phi(12)$=4<6.

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck ?

Comment: @ Jp McCarthy: Just the first argument that came to my mind. Were $f=x^6+1$ irreducible we would get a field of degree $6$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ by adjoining a root of $f$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. But on the other hand each root of $f$ is a $12$-th root of unity and hence lies in the $12$-th cyclotomic field over $\mathbb{Q}$ which only has degree $4$.