# How to prove $x^{2k}+1$ is irreducible over the rational numbers

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I guess this is a very stupid question but I am stuck. Obviously $x^{2k}+1$ has no root in $\mathbb Q$, but I guess this does not imply it must be irreducible. Is there some very easy way to prove this?

Comment: The implication $$p(x)\text{ has no roots in }\Bbb K\implies p(x)\text{ is irreducible}$$ is true when $\deg p=2$ or $\deg p=3$. For higher degrees, it fails quite often. For instance, all polynomials of degree $\ge 2$ are reducible in $\Bbb R$, though the ones of even degree might not have roots. Classic example: in $\Bbb R[x]$, $$k\ge2\implies x^{2^k}+1=\left(x^{2^{k-1}}-\sqrt2 x^{2^{k-2}}+1\right)\left(x^{2^{k-1}}+\sqrt2 x^{2^{k-2}}+1\right)$$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976277

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$ x^n + 1 $ is irreducible in $ \mathbf Q[x] $ precisely when $ n $ is a power of 2. Indeed, if $ n $ is not a power of 2 then write $ n = 2^{v_2(n)} k $ with $ k $ odd, then $ x^{2^{v_2(n)}} + 1 $ divides $ x^n + 1 $. To show the converse, note that $ [\mathbf Q(\zeta_{2^k}) : \mathbf Q] = \varphi(2^k) = 2^{k-1} $, so the $ 2^k $th cyclotomic polynomial is of degree $ 2^{k-1} $, however we have $ x^{2^k} - 1 = (x^{2^{k-1}} - 1)(x^{2^{k-1}} + 1) $ which implies that the $ 2^k $th cyclotomic polynomial is actually $ x^{2^{k-1}} + 1 $, and hence this polynomial is irreducible for $ k \geq 0 $.

Another argument can be obtained by noting that the prime $ 2 $ is totally ramified in the ring of integers $ \mathbf Z[\zeta_n] $, and therefore we might guess that $ x^n + 1 $ becomes Eisenstein at $ 2 $ with an appropriate variable transformation. This guess is correct: the binomial coefficient $ C(n, k) $ is always divisible by $ 2 $ for $ 1 \leq k \leq n-1 $ when $ n $ is a power of $ 2 $, therefore $ (x+1)^n + 1 $ is Eisenstein at $ 2 $, and thus irreducible in $ \mathbf Q[x] $.

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Another stupid question, why $x^k+1$ divides $x^n+1$?

Comment: It doesn't - my bad. I fixed that part of the argument. The idea is that you can use the elementary factorization identity $ x^d + 1 = (x + 1)(x^{d-1} - x^{d-2} \ldots + 1) $ which holds for $ d $ odd, and substitute $ x \to x^{2^{v_2(n)}} $.

Answer (score 3):

This is false. For instance,
$$x^{12}+1= (x^4+1) (x^8-x^4+1)$$

The factorization of $x^{2k}+1$ appears in the factorization of $x^{4k}-1$, which is given by [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).

Comment: Cool, so is there any criterion to judge for which k this is true?

Comment: Like how do I know $x^4+1$ and $x^8+1$ is irreducible or not?

Comment: But your example is the case k=6......

Comment: @lhf $x^k+1$ is irreducible precisely for $k$ a power of $2$. In particular, $x^8+1$ is irreducible.